# How to remove Merged region using Apache POI? (Duplicate Data)

Tags: java, apache-poi

So recently I had an issue which was related to the below question

[How to remove Merged region using POI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22960368/how-to-remove-merged-region-using-poi)

Although the above did partially solve my issue, I wanted to duplicate the data to other un-merged cells.
I couldn't find any guide or function in the library itself to resolve this and so I created a newer version based on the above

```
        HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(file.getInputStream());
        HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

        for(int i=0; i < sheet.getNumMergedRegions(); i++)
        {
            CellRangeAddress addresses = sheet.getMergedRegion(i);
            for(int x=addresses.getFirstRow()+1;x<addresses.getLastRow();x++)
            {
                HSSFCell cell = sheet.getRow(addresses.getFirstRow()).getCell(addresses.getFirstColumn());
                for(int y=addresses.getFirstColumn();y<=addresses.getLastColumn();y++)
                {
                    sheet.getRow(x).getCell(y).setCellStyle(cell.getCellStyle());
                    switch (cell.getCellType())
                    {
                        case _NONE:{}
                            break;
                        case BLANK:{}
                            break;
                        case STRING:{sheet.getRow(x).getCell(y).setCellValue(cell.getRichStringCellValue());}
                            break;
                        case BOOLEAN:{sheet.getRow(x).getCell(y).setCellValue(cell.getBooleanCellValue());}
                            break;
                        case NUMERIC:{sheet.getRow(x).getCell(y).setCellValue(cell.getNumericCellValue());}
                            break;
                        case FORMULA:{sheet.getRow(x).getCell(y).setCellValue(cell.getCellFormula());}
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The above resolved my issue, but as you can see I had to use a switch case. So I was hoping if there are any other better ways to this?